# Given $m$, $n$, and $x$ is it possible to know whether there exists a $c$ and $i$ such that $m^ci \equiv x\pmod{mn - 1}$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

The full problem is as follows;

Given $m, n, x$;

$\\m, n, x \in \mathbb{Z^+}$

$\\1 \lt m, n$

$\\1 \lt x \lt mn - 1$

can we know that whether there exists a $c$ and $i$ satisfying

$\\i, c \in \mathbb{Z^+}\text{,} \qquad 0 \lt c\text{,} \qquad 1 \le i \lt x$ and
$$m^ci \equiv x\pmod{mn - 1}$$

and how can we do that?

Here is what I know for now;
I know that if $c$ and $i$ exists there must exist a $c'$ satisfying

$\\c' \in \mathbb{Z^+}\text{,} \qquad 0 \lt c'$ and
$$n^{c'}i \equiv x\pmod{mn -1}$$

And let's say $gcd(i, mn - 1) = d$

if $1 \lt d$
$$\frac{m^ci}{d} \equiv \frac{x}{d}\bmod{\frac{mn - 1}{d}}$$
and if $\frac xd$ is not an integer, we can say that there is no $c$ and $i$ satisfying these conditions.

Comment: You have defined a function of 4 variables, $f(c,m,n,i)$, but you haven't told us anything about $c$. You have told us that $s$ must be a positive integer, but there's is no $s$ in your function. And then you write about $f(s)$, as if $f$ were a function of one variable instead of four variables. Can you edit your question, please, so it makes some sense?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I have made a mistake while transferring my problem. Corrected.

Comment: You still have an $s$ in there, and you are still using $f$ for both a function of four variables and for a function of one variable.

Comment: They meant the same function since we know that m and n are fixed and on each iteration I is given. I fixed all now.

Comment: So: given $m$, $n$, and $x$, you want to know whether there exist $c$ and $i$ such that $m^ci\equiv x\bmod{mn-1}$ – is that it?

Comment: Given $m$, $n$, and $x$ I want to know whether there exists a $c$ and $i$ such that $i \lt x$ and $m^c \times i\pmod{(m \times n) - 1} \equiv x$

Comment: I suspect there's no way to do that that's any easier than just doing a systematic search through values of $c$ and $i$.

Comment: Is there a way to prove this?

Comment: If I find a way, I'll let you know.

Comment: I have restructured the question to make it more clear thanks to @Gerry Myerson

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't think there'd be anything like a general answer to the question. It is a finite question, though – for any $m,n,x$, there are only finitely many values of $c$ and $x$ that you need to try to see whether there is a solution.

Here's an example of what can happen. Say $m=n=10$. Then $m^c\bmod{mn-1}$ takes on only the values $1$ and $10$. So we get $i\equiv x\bmod{99}$ or $10i\equiv x\bmod{99}$, with $1\le i<x$. The condition $i<x$ rules out $i\equiv x\bmod{99}$, so all we really have is $10i\equiv x\bmod{99}$. This is the same as $i\equiv10x\bmod{99}$, $1\le i<x$. This has no solution for $x=2,3,4,\dots,9$, has the solution $i=1$ when $x=10$, has no solution for $x=11,12,\dots,19$, and so on.

On the other hand, if $mn-1$ is a prime, and $m$ is a primitive root modulo $mn-1$, then $m^c$ takes on all nonzero values $\bmod{mn-1}$, so there's a solution for every $x$.

I think any comprehensive answer would be a huge collection of different cases, and might amount to no more than, there's a solution when there's a solution.